# How do I use .split() to break up a string into much smaller strings?

Tags: javascript, slice

I am making a code that is supposed to split up the alphabet into each letter on a different line. When I press the submit button, instead of displaying the letters, it does absolutely nothing at all. I am not sure why it is not working.

The output should be:
A:
B:
C:
D:
etc...

Any help is appreciated, but please do not use JQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:hi="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My String Prototype</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "#">
    <input type="submit" id = "sub" value="Submit" onclick = "show_alphabet();"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_alphabet () {
        var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        str.prototype.sendArray= function (){
            str.split("");
        };
        var arr = str.sendArray();
        for (var i=0;i>arr.length;i++){
            document.writeln(arr+":");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

THANKS!

Comment: Your function does not `return` anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this looks like homework, you don't get the answer outright.

1) When you split a string, you pick which character to split on.
Ex: Splitting ("A B") (A then space then B). Returns an array with 2 elements. A & B.

2) You don't need all the string prototype stuff like you see in online help.
var arr = str.split(... works fine.

3) Your greater than sign should be less than in for loop. You wnat to repeat while i is less than the length, not greater.

4) You don't want to writeln arr. You want to writeln arr[i], or the i'th element of the array.

5) To do the newline in HTML replace ":" with "`<br />`"

Comment: This was not homework, but thank you for explaining it instead of just giving me the answer. I got the code to word using your tips. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to `split` the string into characters if you can already do that by default:

```js
var string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += '\n' + string[i];
  }
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

1. Need to use `String.prototype.sendArray =`
2. Need to `return` a value
3. The `i > arr.length` will never be true
4. Need to use `arr[i]` to access the current element. `arr` is the entire array

This appears to work as expected:

```
function show_alphabet () {
    var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String.prototype.sendArray = function (){
        return str.split("");
    };
    var arr = str.sendArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        document.write(arr[i] + ":");
    }
}
```

Comment: @roshen_amin Sorry you see that because I initially missed the `arr[i]` in the `for` body. It has since been added.

Answer (score 0):

There are these issues in your code:

1. Your `sendArray()` method needs to return its result.
2. You need to use `String.prototype.sendArray = function() {...}`, not `str.prototype.sendArray = ...`.
3. When you create a new method on the prototype, you refer to the current instance as `this`, not `str`.
4. You have to reference the array item with `arr[i]`.
5. Your comparison operation in your `for` statement is backwards.

I don't see why you're creating a new method that does nothing more than `.split()`, but if you want to do that, then you need to return the new value and use `this` instead of `str` and use `String.prototype`:

```
    String.prototype.sendArray= function (){
        return this.split("");
    };
```

---

But, you don't really need that new method at all.  Here's a working snippet with those above items fixed/changed:

```js
    function show_alphabet () {
        var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var arr = str.split("");
        for (var i=0;i < arr.length;i++){
            document.write(arr[i] + "<br>");
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    show_alphabet();
```

Or, using your `sendArray()` method:

```js
    String.prototype.sendArray= function (){
        return this.split("");
    };

    function show_alphabet () {
        var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var arr = str.sendArray();
        for (var i=0;i < arr.length;i++){
            document.write(arr[i] + "<br>");
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    show_alphabet();
```

---

**Prototype Usage Explanation**

Here's a bit of explanation about the `.prototype` issue.  The `.prototype` property is a direct property of a constructor function, not an individual object.  That means it's a property of `String`, not `str`.  Once you change it on `String`, then all objects created from that constructor will automatically inherit that change.  So, when you add something to `String.prototype`, it will automatically be available on `str` as a direct method.

Then, when that method is invoked, the value of `this` will point to the current object so to reference a method or property on the current object from a prototyped method, you use `this` as the base.  So, in this case, you would call `this.split("")` so split the current string.